# Using certain props to trigger a useEffect() React hook, but referencing others in the effect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React use case where a component  gets a `category` prop passed down, and also has a local state value `limit`. My desired behavior is:

1. When a `category` gets selected, the `limit` gets reset to 10 if it's currently higher than 10.
2. When the `category` gets cleared, the `limit` gets reset to 50 if it's currently lower than 50.
3. While the `category` is unchanged, the user can choose any `limit` they want.

I have this behavior set in an effect hook like so (more complete example at bottom):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (category && limit > 10) {
      setLimit(10);
    } else if (!category && limit < 50) {
      setLimit(50);
    }
  }, [category]);
```

This works fine, but runs afoul of the [react-hooks/exhaustive-deps linter rule](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) which says that I should be including `limit` in the dependency array. I don't actually want that, because I don't want a user-initiated change of the `limit` to trigger anything, and I want a user to be able to exceed the high/low thresholds while the category isn't changing.

Is there a "right" way to accomplish this that respects the rules of hooks while not introducing several more hooks in order to juggle all of the different possible props/state transitions?

More complete example:

```
function App() {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setCategory(!category)}>Toggle category</button>
      <List category={category} />
    </div>
  );
}

function List({ category }) {
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);

  // Change the limit when category changes
  // BUT only if limit is above/below a threshold!
  useEffect(() => {
    if (category && limit > 10) {
      setLimit(10);
    } else if (!category && limit < 50) {
      setLimit(50);
    }
  }, [category]);

  return (
    <div>
      <select value={limit} onChange={e => setLimit(e.target.value)}>
        {[5, 10, 25, 50, 100].map(d => (
          <option key={d}>{d}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <div>Category is {category ? "on" : "off"}</div>
      <div>Would show {limit} items</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `ref` to keep track of the previous category? They are the equivalent to [instance variables](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) in function components.

That way you can do a comparison and only run the effect code if the category has changed e.g.

```
const prevCat = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
  if (prevCat.current === category) return;

  prevCat.current = category;
  ...
}, [category, limit]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to [`useReducer()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) to manage `limit` together with `category`, and pass both to your component instead of using local state. This way the component will be rendered only when either value changes (or both).

```
const initialState = {
    category: true,
    limit: 10
};

function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'toggleCategory':
        if (state.category) {
            return {category: false, limit: Math.min(50, state.limit)};
        }
        else {
            return {category: true, limit: Math.max(10, state.limit)};
        }
    case 'setLimit':
        return {...state, limit: action.limit};
    default:
        throw new Error();
    }
}

function App() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    // React guarantees that dispatch function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders.
    // This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.
    const toggleCategory = useCallback(() => dispatch({type: 'toggleCategory'}));
    const setLimit = useCallback(limit => dispatch({type: 'setLimit', limit}));
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button onClick={toggleCategory}>Toggle category</button>
            <List {...state} setLimit={setLimit} />
        </div>
    );
}

function List({ category, limit, setLimit }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <select value={limit} onChange={e => setLimit(e.target.value)}>
                {[5, 10, 25, 50, 100].map(d => (
                    <option key={d}>{d}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
            <div>Category is {category ? "on" : "off"}</div>
            <div>Would show {limit} items</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional version of setter:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLimit((currentLimit) => {
        if (category && currentLimit > 10) {
          return 10;
        } else if (!category && currentLimit < 50) {
          return 50;
        } else return currentLimit;
    });
  }, [category]);
```